# curl error 411 when migrating from PHP 5.3 to 5.6

Tags: php, curl

I'm migrating from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.6.3.
When doing a curl request, it now gives me an error:

> The requested URL returned error: 411 Length Required

All the data is the same. A vardump on the msg returns a string of 620. The length is correct, nothing of the variables are changed and contain the same data whether it is PHP 5.3 or PHP 5.6.3.

So in short; I have exact the same setup, data, format etc. but now curl gives a 411 error.

**This is a snippet of my code:**

```
$handle   = curl_init();

curl_setopt($handle,     CURLOPT_URL, $this->_url);
curl_setopt($handle,     CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($handle,     CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml","SOAPAction: ".$request."","Content-length: ".strlen($msg))); 
curl_setopt($handle,     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle,     CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $msg);
curl_setopt($handle,     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($handle,     CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 

curl_setopt($handle,     CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt($handle,     CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->_httpUser.':'.$this->_httpPassword);

$response = curl_exec($handle);
```

**PHPINFO curl:**

> cURL support  enabled
>
> cURL Information  7.39.0
>
> Age   3
>
> Features
>
> AsynchDNS     Yes
>
> CharConv  No
>
> Debug     No
>
> GSS-Negotiate     No
>
> IDN   Yes
>
> IPv6  Yes
>
> krb4  No
>
> Largefile     Yes
>
> libz  Yes
>
> NTLM  Yes
>
> NTLMWB    No
>
> SPNEGO    Yes
>
> SSL   Yes
>
> SSPI  Yes
>
> TLS-SRP   No
>
> Protocols     dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
>
> Host  i386-pc-win32
>
> SSL Version   OpenSSL/1.0.1i
>
> ZLib Version  1.2.7.3
>
> libSSH Version    libssh2/1.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had to remove the content-length part since curl does this automatically for non 'put' requests.

The reason why my code worked under PHP 5.3 and not with PHP 5.6.3 is unknown to me. Yet this is the solution.